# Using sed to find/replace text in a certain file

Tags: bash, sed, posix

I have a html file that I'm trying to use `sed` to automatically find a particular line and have this replaced but I am having no joy so far..

`<div infinite-scroll='tabs[tabIndex].FeedService.loadFeed(false, tabs[tabIndex].FeedService.filters)'>`

I would like to simply grab the entire line and replace to the following line using `sed`

`<div infinite-scroll-labs="tabs[tabIndex].FeedService.loadFeed(false, tabs[tabIndex].FeedService.filters)" infinite-scroll-labs-container="window">`

// my attempt..

`sed -r --posix "infinite-scroll='tabs[tabIndex].FeedService.loadFeed(false, tabs[tabIndex].FeedService.filters, search.text, search.dateFrom, search.dateTo)' infinite-scroll-disabled='tabs[tabIndex].FeedService.busy || tabs[tabIndex].FeedService.noMoreResults || !tabs[tabIndex].active || tabs[tabIndex].FeedService.initialLoad' infinite-scroll-distance='1' infinite-scroll-immediate-check='false'\infinite-scroll-labs="tabs[tabIndex].FeedService.loadFeed(false, tabs[tabIndex].FeedService.filters, search.text, search.dateFrom, search.dateTo)" infinite-scroll-labs-container="window" app/feed.html > $cur_dir/www/feed.html`

How is the best way to go about this?

Comment: don't use regex for processing html files...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sure that's the exact line you want to change, then maybe this will work:

```
sed "s#^\(<div infinite-scroll\)='\(tabs\[tabIndex\]\.FeedService\.loadFeed(false, tabs\[tabIndex\]\.FeedService\.filters)\)'>\$#\1-labs=\"\2infinite-scroll-labs-container=\"window\">#"
```